# AWS Kinesis Data Firehose outputs file to S3 bucket. How/Where transform the data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-kinesis-firehose, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have configured eventbridge rule to output(target) to Kinesis Data firehose and eventually Data firehose to S3 Bucket. Data is in JSON format.
Data is getting delivered to S3 bucket with no issues.
I have created a Glue Crawler pointing to S3 bucket which creates table schema/metadata in Glue Catalog and data in AWS Athena.

I am facing two issues currently :

1. Data written to S3 bucket by Firehose is writing it as Single line json which means if there are 5 records in json , AWS Athena queries only top record because it is not delimited by new line (\n). When records aren't separated by a newline character (\n) it will always return 1 record as per AWS Athena docs.
   https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/select-count-query-athena-json-records/
   How I can transform these records to single line and where i should do this ? In firehose ?

2.In Json data , there are some columns with special characters and AWS Athena docs said column
cannot have special characters like (forward slash etc.)? How i can remove special
character/rename the column name , where i should transform this data ? In ETL Glue Job ? After
crawler has created the table schema ?

I understand in Kinesis Firehose we can transform source records with AWS Lambda but i am not able to solve above 2 issues with it.

Update:

I was able to resolve Issue first by creating lamda function and calling from Data firehose. What logic I can include in same lamda to remove special character from the KeyName. Code below :

Example - in json if the value is like    "RelatedAWSResources:0/type": "AWS::Config::ConfigRule" -- Remove Special Character from the KeyName only make it like    "RelatedAWSResources0type": "AWS::Config::ConfigRule"

```
import json
import boto3
import base64

output = []

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    for record in event['records']:
        payload = base64.b64decode(record['data']).decode('utf-8')
        print('payload:', payload)
        
        row_w_newline = payload + "\n"
        print('row_w_newline type:', type(row_w_newline))
        row_w_newline = base64.b64encode(row_w_newline.encode('utf-8'))
        
        output_record = {
            'recordId': record['recordId'],
            'result': 'Ok',
            'data': row_w_newline
        }
        output.append(output_record)

    print('Processed {} records.'.format(len(event['records'])))
    
    return {'records': output}
```

Comment: " i am not able to solve above 2 issues with it." - why you are not able? What is your current lambda code? What is wrong with the code?

Comment: I was able to Solve Issue 1 - I created lamda function which uses python script and it transform each json to single line and i call this lamda function from data firehose which transform my json file. Can you tell me how to approach Issue no 2 , should i write another lamda which remove special character from json Key. I am not able to find any examples on same or should i transform this using Glue ETL jobs ?

Comment: You can do this in same function. No need for second one.

Comment: I have shared my code. Can you suggest what logic i can include to remove special character in the same function

Comment: You have to modify your `row_w_newline` so have the new keys.